# Databricks - Extract Complicated Array List into Columns

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, arraylist, pyspark, databricks

I am new to Databricks and have some difficulties in transforming a complicated array list into multiple individual columns.

I have the following column for one sample row in my dataset.

```
priceItems                                                                                            |
[["itemType": 1, "price":12345, "priceLabel": "AB 123", "priceName": "Subtotal", "priceUSD": 123.45], |
["itemType": 2, "price":67890, "priceLabel": "CD 456", "priceName": "Delivery", "priceUSD": 678.90],  |
["itemType": 3, "price":13579, "priceLabel": "EF 135", "priceName": "Discount", "priceUSD": 135.79]]  |
```

I would like to transform to the following output columns:

```
itemType1 | price1 | priceLabel1 | priceName1 | priceUSD1 \
1         | 12345  | AB 123      | Subtotal   | 123.45

itemType2 | price2 | priceLabel2 | priceName2 | priceUSD2 \
2         | 67890  | BC 456      | Delivery   | 678.90

itemType3 | price3 | priceLabel3 | priceName3 | priceUSD3
3         | 13479  | DE 135      | Discount   | 135.79
```

I tried using explode and getItems functions but am getting the error that 'list' object has no attribute 'withColumn'. Can someone please help me out with this activity?

The Schema of the priceItems column is as follows.

```
root
|--priceItems: array (nullable) = true
   |--element: struct (containsNull = true)
   |--itemType: integer (nullable = True)
   |--price: double (nullable = true)
   |--priceLabel: string (nullable = true)
   |--priceName: string (nullable = true)
   |--priceUSD: double (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Could you please the data and schema example in the question ? Not able to recreate the data in Spark otherwise.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The data is system generated. I have given a sample data point in the first section but am unable to recreate the entire dataset myself. I've also given the schema of the column in question. Do let me know if you need any further information!

Comment: Hi @Lazarus, based on the 1 example row, the output should be 3 row records with 5 columns each or 1 row record with 15 column?